# AWS Serverless Function: Can't access methods of aws-sdk objects..."is not a function"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I have a serverless function inside a CloudFormation template meant to instantiate an AWS Connect instance. However, I can't access any methods on the aws-sdk object, the error thrown is "connect.createInstance is not a function". When I call getOwnPropertyNames on the object it returns the following, instead of the methods I'm trying to access:
[
'config',
'isGlobalEndpoint',
'endpoint',
'_events',
'MONITOR_EVENTS_BUBBLE',
'CALL_EVENTS_BUBBLE',
'_originalConfig',
'_clientId'
]

As a test I instantiated an S3 object and calling getOwnPropertyNames on that returns the exact same thing. What am I doing wrong? I'm following the canonical form here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html#createInstance-property

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
Parameters:
  IdentityManagementType:
    Description: The type of identity management for your Amazon Connect users.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: ["SAML", "CONNECT_MANAGED", "EXISTING_DIRECTORY"]
    Default: "SAML"
  InboundCallsEnabled:
    Description: Whether your contact center handles incoming contacts.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
    Default: true
  InstanceAlias:
    Description: The name for your instance.
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 62
  OutboundCallsEnabled:
    Description: Whether your contact center allows outbound calls.
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]
    Default: true
  DirectoryId:
    Description: Optional. The identifier for the directory, if using this type of Identity Management.
    Type: String
  ClientToken:
    Description: Optional. The idempotency token. Used for concurrent deployments
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 500
  Region:
    Description: Region to place the AWS Connect Instance
    Type: String
    Default: us-east-1

#Handler for optional values
Conditions:
  HasClientToken: !Not
    - !Equals
      - ""
      - !Ref ClientToken
  HasDirectoryId: !Not
    - !Equals
      - ""
      - !Ref DirectoryId

Resources:
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AWSConnect
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - connect:*
                Resource: arn:aws:connect:*:*
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

  CreateConnectInstance:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Description: Invoke a function to create an AWS Connect instance
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 8
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Tracing: Active
      Environment:
        Variables:
          IdentityManagementType:
            Ref: IdentityManagementType
          InboundCallsEnabled:
            Ref: InboundCallsEnabled
          InstanceAlias:
            Ref: InstanceAlias
          OutboundCallsEnabled:
            Ref: OutboundCallsEnabled
          Region:
            Ref: Region
          #Optional Values
          ClientToken: !If
            - HasClientToken
            - !Ref ClientToken
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
          DirectoryId: !If
            - HasClientToken
            - !Ref ClientToken
            - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      InlineCode: |
        var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        var params = {
          IdentityManagementType: process.env.IdentityManagementType,
          InboundCallsEnabled: process.env.InboundCallsEnabled,
          OutboundCallsEnabled: process.env.OutboundCallsEnabled,
          ClientToken: process.env.ClientToken,
          DirectoryId: process.env.DirectoryId,
          InstanceAlias: process.env.InstanceAlias,
        };
        var connect = new AWS.Connect({apiVersion: '2017-08-08'});
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(connect)); // ***Not what's expected***
        var createConnectRequest = connect.createInstance(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
          else     console.log(data);
        }); // ***connect.createInstance is not a function***

  InvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    DependsOn: CreateConnectInstance
    Version: "1.0"
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !Sub ${CreateConnectInstance.Arn}
```

Comment: The Node.js Lambda runtime includes AWS SDK 2.771.0. You might want to verify outside of Lambda if that specific version of the SDK supports Connect's createInstance method.

Comment: As I am pinning the apiVersion explicitly, and no error is thrown upon instantiation of that object, I'd expect the method to exist and the documentation I linked to apply:

        var connect = new AWS.Connect({apiVersion: '2017-08-08'});

If this is not a correct assumption someone please chime in.

Comment: Incorrect assumption afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Connect `createInstance` method is not available in the AWS SDK that is currently deployed with the AWS Lambda Node.js [runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) (v2.771.0 at the time of writing). It looks like the [createInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_CreateInstance.html) API is in a preview release.

That function was introduced in [v2.797.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/releases/tag/v2.797.0). You can verify this locally (outside of Lambda). I verified this with a binary-chop approach to testing AWS SDK versions between 2.771.0 and current (2.809.0) and the following, simple code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const connect = new AWS.Connect({apiVersion: '2017-08-08'});
connect.createInstance('fred');
```

The [changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) shows this for v2.797.0 (among other things):

> feature: Connect: This release adds a set of Amazon Connect APIs to
> programmatically control instance creation, modification, description
> and deletion.

You can [upload a compatible version of the SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-aws-sdk-latest-version/) (in your Lambda package or via a Lambda Layer) to get access to this function.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks a lot, and bonus points for explaining your methodology and linking changelog and solution.

Comment: As a side-note it seems like bad practice for the api to not throw an error when you instantiate an object with an apiVersion that it is not actually using.

Comment: It *is* using that API version and it does support the Connect API. The problem you're hitting is that [createInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_CreateInstance.html) is in a preview release of Connect.